# ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL for nova-consoleauth and nova-scheduler

Tags: openstack-nova

In openstack controller node,

`nova-consoleauth` and `nova-scheduler` are dead due to having the same error, `ERROR oslo_service.service ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL`.

`nova-compute` service in compute node is fine. I have also allowed `rabbitmq` port 5672. Still I cannot resolve the `Invalid IPv6 Error`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the misleading configuration in the openstack documentation.
You need to remove `transport_url` from `[default]` section and put the following in the `nova.conf`.

```
[default]
...
rpc_backend = rabbit
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
rabbit_host = controller
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_password = password
```